# Numpy Cannot cast ufunc multiply output from dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, int

I'd like to multiply an `int16` array but a `float` array, with auto rounding, but this fails :

```
import numpy

A = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=numpy.int16)
B = numpy.array([0.5, 2.1, 3, 4], dtype=numpy.float64)

A *= B
```

I get:

> TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc multiply output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int16') with casting rule 'same_kind'

Comment: It seems it's possible with `numpy.multiply(A, B, out=A, casting='unsafe')` but that's way much longer syntax!
Is there a way to set casting='unsafe' in numpy by default?

Comment: See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6499/files

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**2 ways to solve this:**

You can solve this **by replacing**

```
A *= B
```

**with**

```
A = (A * B)
```

**or** with

```
numpy.multiply(A, B, out=A, casting='unsafe')
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to multiply the two arrays and take only the integer part as follows:

```
In [2]: (A*B).astype(int)
Out[2]: array([ 0,  4,  9, 16])
```

**Timing Constraints:**

```
In [8]: %timeit (A*B).astype(int)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 µs per loop

In [9]: %timeit np.multiply(A, B, out=A, casting='unsafe')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.01 µs per loop
```

Comment: OP wants to do the multiplication in place

Comment: How fast is it compared to `numpy.multiply(A, B, out=A, casting='unsafe')` ?

Comment: @ali_m Nowhere does the OP mention they want to do the multiplication in place. Their only comment was that the longer way was "way much longer syntax".

Comment: @SethMMorton Well, both the example given in the question and the workaround the OP posted in the comments are explicitly performing in place multiplication.

Comment: @ali_m I don't disagree with that, but based on this question and [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38673878/1399279) it seems the OP is more interested in terseness than an in-place operation. Having said that, I think the assumption that they want an in place operation is good because of the examples given and that in-place saves having to type `A = `, but I always think it is safer to wait for the OP to explicitly make it clear what they want rather than make assumptions.

Comment: @SethMMorton Perfectly explicit questions are very rare on SO - if you wait for total clarity you are likely to wait forever. The best we can do is to ask for clarification in the comments and try to infer what the OP wants based on the evidence available. Given that my answer was accepted I'm reasonably confident that I guessed right, but the OP can always unaccept my answer if they change their mind ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.float_(A)
A *= B
```

try this. I think are different array type you get fail.

Cast