# Redefine *= operator in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subclass

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673531/multiply-numpy-int-and-float-arrays) and [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6499/files), this doesn't work anymore in numpy 1.7+ :

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=numpy.int16)
B = numpy.array([0.5, 2.1, 3, 4], dtype=numpy.float64)
A *= B
```

A workaround is to do:

```
def mult(a,b):
    numpy.multiply(a, b, out=a, casting="unsafe")

def add(a,b):
    numpy.add(a, b, out=a, casting="unsafe")

mult(A,B)
```

but that's way too long to write for each matrix operation!

**How can override the numpy `*=` operator to do this by default?**

Should I subclass something?

Comment: `A *= B` saves you only 3 characters over `mult(A,B)`.  Can you articulate why you need to have the shortest method possible?

Comment: @SethMMorton : *better explicit than implicit* : `*=` is standard among all major programming languages ; having to define a `mult` function is not natural

Comment: What do you want `A` to end up as here?

Comment: @Eric As `A` is an int array, and that we do inplace `*=`, I want `A` to stay an int at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `np.set_numeric_ops` to override array arithmetic methods:

```
import numpy as np

def unsafe_multiply(a, b, out=None):
    return np.multiply(a, b, out=out, casting="unsafe")

np.set_numeric_ops(multiply=unsafe_multiply)

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=np.int16)
B = np.array([0.5, 2.1, 3, 4], dtype=np.float64)
A *= B

print(repr(A))
# array([ 0,  4,  9, 16], dtype=int16)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a general function and pass the intended attribute to it:

```
def calX(a,b, attr):
    try:
        return getattr(numpy, attr)(a, b, out=a, casting="unsafe")
    except AttributeError:
        raise Exception("Please enter a valid attribute")
```

Demo:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> A = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=numpy.int16)
>>> B = numpy.array([0.5, 2.1, 3, 4], dtype=numpy.float64)
>>> calX(A, B, 'multiply')
array([ 0,  4,  9, 16], dtype=int16)
>>> calX(A, B, 'subtract')
array([ 0,  1,  6, 12], dtype=int16)
```

Note that if you want to override the result you can just assign the function's return to the first matrix.

```
A = calX(A, B, 'multiply')
```

Comment: Nice but this is not shorter than `mult(A,B)`  with `def mult(a,b):    numpy.multiply(a, b, out=a, casting="unsafe")`... What I want is override `A*=B`

Comment: @Basj This is a general way, which makes you don't define a function for all operations. Also you don't need to override anything.

Comment: @Basj If you consist to use in-place operators you better to create a custom matrix object and define it's operators manually which still you'd need to do this for all the operators.