# Calling a lambda with a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

While familiarizing myself with `numpy`, I noticed an interesting behaviour in `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
scale = lambda x: x * 3

scale(arr) # Gives array([3, 6, 9])
```

Contrast this with normal Python lists:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
scale = lambda x: x * 3

scale(arr) # Gives [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

I'm curious as to how this is possible. Does a `numpy` array override the multiplication operator or something?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `lambda`... anyway, `numpy` arrays override most operators to perform *vectorized* operations. That's one of the key features of `numpy`...

Comment: see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`numpy.ndarray` [overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892616/python-multiplication-override) the `*` operator by defining its own `__mul__` method. Likewise for `+`, `-`, etc. This allows for vector arithmetic.

Answer (score 6):

Its all about [Overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673878/redefine-operator-in-numpy) operators in numpy

You can learn numpy.arry [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

Let us focus on your lamda function for each;

**1. numpy array :**

```
arr = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
type(arr)
scale = lambda x: x * 3 
scale(arr)
```

this takes each element from array

**2. normal list:**

```
a =[1,2,3]
type(a)
scale = lambda x: x * 3 
scale(a)
```

this takes full list as x and multiplies the list here itself

Answer (score 1):

These are two different objects which behaves differently when you use * operator on them.

1. In the first case you generate a numpy array. In this case, * operator was overloaded for performing multiplication. i.e. every element will be multiplied by 3.
2. In the second case you generate a list. In this case the * operator is treated as a [repetition operator](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=CUIgM3e-I5gC&pg=PT254&lpg=PT254&dq=repetition%20operator%20on%20lists%20python&source=bl&ots=r3lwhdzy4j&sig=k2F125SugUICixliHYZZnfuFpS0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdoJDnjefSAhWMLcAKHZUxAOIQ6AEISDAI#v=onepage&q=repetition%20operator%20on%20lists%20python&f=false), and the entire list is repeated 3 times.

code example:

```
type(np.array([1,2,3]))
type([1, 2, 3])
```

result:

```
numpy.ndarray
list
```

Comment: I think the types are reversed

Comment: I now fixed it.