# How to read a audio file in Python similar to Matlab audioread?

Tags: python, matlab, audio

I'm using `wavefile.read()` in Python to import a audio file to Python. What I want is read a audio file where every sample is in double and normalized to -1.0 to +1.0 similar to Matlab `audioread()` function. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [read](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#soundfile.read) function of the [PySoundFile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySoundFile/) package.  By default it will return exactly what you request: a numpy array containing the sound file samples in double-precision (`Float64`) format in the range `-1.0` to `+1.0`.

Answer (score 8):

Use SciPy:

```py
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

fs, signal = wav.read(file_name)

signal = signal / 32767 # 2**15 - 1
```

You need to divide it by the maximal value of Int16 if you want to have exactly the same thing as in Matlab.

**Warning:** if the WAV file is Int32 encoded, you need to normalize it by the maximal value of Int32.

**NOTE:** Using the following shortcut: `signal /= 32767` fails due to [the numpy cast issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38673531/17342313).