# How can I multiply column of the int numpy array to the float digit and stays in int?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
 >>> b
 array([[ 2,  2],
        [ 6,  4],
        [10,  6]])
```

I want to multiply first column by float number, and as result I need int number, because when I doing:

```
>>> b[:,0] *= 2.1
```

It says:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc multiply output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

I need the array that looks like:

```
array([[ 4,  2],
       [12,  4],
       [21,  6]])
```

Comment: `b[:,0] = b[:,0]*2.1 `

Comment: wow, why this works?

Comment: And cast to int with: `(b[:,0]*2.1).astype(int)`

Comment: @AntonvBR casting is not needed.

Comment: @UmangGupta By looking at OP's expected output I think it is needed though.

Comment: @karambaq https://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Typecasting see implicit conversion section, that might hint on why it works.

Comment: Evidently `*=` has tighter casting rules than plain `=`,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiply numpy int and float arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673531/multiply-numpy-int-and-float-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `b[:,0] *= 2.1` may not work but `b[:,0] = b[:,0]* 2.1` works.

Answer (score 7):

@Umang Gupta gave a solution to your problem.  I was curious myself as to why this worked, so I'm posting what I found as additional context.  FWIW this question has already been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673531/multiply-numpy-int-and-float-arrays), but that answer also doesn't really walk through what's happening as much as I would have liked, so here's my attempt:

Using the `*=` operator calls the [`__imul__()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.__imul__.html#numpy.ndarray.__imul__) special method for in-place multiplication of Numpy ndarrays, which in turn [calls](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/mixins.py#L157) the universal function (ufunc) [`multiply()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html).

There are two arguments in `multiply()` which are relevant here: `out` and `casting`.

The `out` argument specifies the output (along with its type).  In the in-place multiplication operator, `out` is set to `self`, i.e. the `ndarray` object which called the multiplication operation.  In particular, [the exact call](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/mixins.py#L40) for `*=` looks like this:

```
ufunc(self, other, out=(self,))
```

^ where `ufunc = multiply`, `self = b` (`ndarray`, type `int64`, and `other = 2.1` (scalar, type `float`)

The `casting` argument, however, determines the rules for what kind of data type casting is permitted as a result of an operation.  [As of Numpy 1.10](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments), the default value for `casting` is `same_kind`, [which means](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.can_cast.html#numpy.can_cast):

> only safe casts or casts within a kind, like float64 to float32, are allowed

Since our `ufunc` call didn't specify a value for the `casting` argument, the default (`same_kind`) is used - but this causes problems because we *have* specified `out` as having an `int64` dtype, which is *not* the same kind as the output of the int-by-float multiplication.  With `same_kind` casting, the `float` result of the operation can't be converted to `int`.  That's why we see this error.

We can replicate this error using `multiply()` explicitly:

```
np.multiply(b, 2.1, out=b)
TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc multiply output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

It is possible to relax the `casting` requirement of `multiply()`, by setting the argument value to `"unsafe"`.  Then, when `out` is also set, the output is coerced to the type of `out`, regardless of whether it's the same kind or not (if possible):

```
np.multiply(b, 2.1, out=b, casting="unsafe")
# specifying int output and allowing casting to be "unsafe" allows re-conversion to int
array([[ 4,  4],
       [12,  8],
       [21, 12]])
```

Using the normal assignment operator to update `b[:,0]`, on the other hand, is ok. That's what @Umang Gupta's solution does.
With:

```
b[:,0] = b[:,0]* 2.1
```

`*` calls the `multiply` ufunc, just like with `*=`.  But since it isn't calling the inplace version of the operation, there's no `out` argument specified, and so no set type for the output. Then, standard typecasting allows ints to upcast to floats:

```
np.multiply(b, 2.1)
# float output
array([[  4.2,   4.2],
       [ 12.6,   8.4],
       [ 21. ,  12.6]])
```

Then the normal assignment operator `=` takes the output of the multiplication and stores it in `b[:,0]`.  Per [the Numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays) on assigning values to indexed arrays:

> Note that assignments may result in changes if assigning higher types to lower types (like floats to ints)

So the problem lies in `*=` operator's automatic setting of the `out` argument without changing the `casting` argument from `same_kind` to `unsafe`.  (Not that this is a bug, just that this is why you are getting an error.)  And the accepted solution gets around that by leveraging automatic "downcasting" properties of assignment in Numpy.  Hope that helps!  (Also, Numpy pros, please feel free to correct any misunderstandings on my part.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Excellent answer